# App working on simulator but not downloaded from appstore in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store, simulator

Good morning,

I have released a new app on the AppStore. It worked fine on simulator, in different devices (both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5) and also worked using testflight.

Today, my app has been approved and it is in the AppStore. The problem is that it works perfectly on iphone 4 but not on iPhone 5.

The log is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0


Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x333363e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158

1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b03195e objc_exception_throw + 26

2   UIKit                           0x354d161c +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 436

3   Torero                          0x00054008 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:27)

4   UIKit                           0x351a5a9c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248

5   UIKit                           0x351a5620 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164

6   UIKit                           0x3519d82e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694

7   UIKit                           0x35145d1a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006

8   UIKit                           0x351457a8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68

9   UIKit                           0x351451ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194

10  GraphicsServices                0x36e5d5f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586

11  GraphicsServices                0x36e5d222 PurpleEventCallback + 30

12  CoreFoundation                  0x3330b3e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30

13  CoreFoundation                  0x3330b386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134

14  CoreFoundation                  0x3330a20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378

15  CoreFoundation                  0x3327d238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352

16  CoreFoundation                  0x3327d0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100

17  UIKit                           0x3519c468 -[UIApplication _run] + 664

18  UIKit                           0x351992b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116

19  Torero                          0x00053e8e main (main.m:16)

20  Torero                          0x00053e44 0x52000 + 7748
```

I think that the problem is in the selector of storyboard in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions so I have copied my old iphone 5 storyboard in a new one, changed name and uploaded a new version of my app.

Do you think it will work? Do you think should I do anything else?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's not clear -- did you ever test on real hardware, or just on different simulator versions.  You should never attempt to release an app without testing on at least one version of real hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Works on simulator but not on device? Check capitalization of your file names. File names on device are case-sensitive, on simulator they are not.

Comment: Yes, I have tested in different devices, both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 and always worked. The only way in which my app hasn´t work is by creating an adhoc profile and testing via itunes. Then I changed my iphone 5 storyboard name, archived and test again via itunes and it worked. I think that my binary was corrupted and my storyboard was missed. thank yoyu very much